# Complile error ConcurrentModificationException, trying to use method for removing the same names

Tags: java, hashmap, static-methods

Im trying to make my `removeItemFromMapByValue` method work together with `removeItemFromMapByValue`, but when i start to compile my code i get that **ConcurrentModificationException**. `removeItemFromMapByValue`  have to remove the same names in values.

```
    public class Solution
        {
            public static HashMap<String, String> createMap()
            {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("Stallone", "Silvest");
                map.put("Morikone", "Enio");
                map.put("Vivaldi","Antonio");
                map.put("Belucci", "Monica");
                map.put("Gudini", "Harry");
                map.put("Verdo", "Dhuzeppe");
                map.put("Maracci", "Bruno");
                map.put("Carleone", "Vito");
                map.put("Bracco", "Luka");
                map.put("Stradivari", "Antonio");
                return map;
            }
            public static void removeTheFirstNameDuplicates(HashMap<String, String> map)
            {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : map.entrySet()){
                    String name = pair.getValue();
                    removeItemFromMapByValue(map, name);
                }
            }
            public static void removeItemFromMapByValue(HashMap<String, String> map, String value)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> copy = new HashMap<String, String>(map);
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair: copy.entrySet())
                {
                    if (pair.getValue().equals(value))
                        map.remove(pair.getKey());
                }
            }
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> map = createMap();
                removeTheFirstNameDuplicates(map);
                System.out.println(map);
            }
        }

Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:926)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:966)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:964)
    at com.javarush.test.level08.lesson08.task05.Solution.removeTheFirstNameDuplicates(Solution.java:32)
    at com.javarush.test.level08.lesson08.task05.Solution.main(Solution.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you get a `ConcurrentModificationException` error when you **compile**? Can you post the exact error message or stack trace if it's actually a runtime error?

Comment: 1) It is NOT a compile error.  It is an exception thrown when you RUN the program.  2) If you get an exception, you should how us the exception stacktrace.

Comment: You're confusing compilation errors, and runtime exceptions. If you get a compilation error, then your question should contain the exact and complete error message from the compiler. If you get a runtime exception, your question should contain the complete stack trace of the exception. Reading the error message is the best way to understand what happens and where. Not reading it makes you and us guess what the problem might be.

Comment: Using removeItemFromMapByValue will result in all values being used if you fixed this problem, not just duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to fix the first method, as this will avoid the error and behave correctly.

```
// remove any duplicated values, leaving one entry.
public static void removeTheFirstNameDuplicates(HashMap<String, String> map) {
     Map<K,V> map2 = invert(invert(map));
     map.clear();
     map.putAll(map2);
}

public static <K, V> Map<V, K> invert(Map<K, V> map) {
     Map<V, K> map2 = new HashMap<>();
     for(Map.Entry<K< V> entry: map.entrySet())
         map2.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
     return map2;
}
```

---

Your compiler will not produce a ConcurrentModifcationException. You should look at the line in in the stack track to see where you are modifying the collection while iterating over it e.g.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair: copy.entrySet())
{
    if (pair.getValue().equals(value))
        map.remove(pair.getKey());
}
```

In this case you are removing an entry while iterating.  A simple solution is to use the Iterator directly. Usually you IDE can do this refactoring.

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = copy.values().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    if (iter.next().equals(value))
        iter.remove();
}
```

The problem with this solution is this is called from a nested and it will remove ALL matching entries as it does in your code. i.e. it will remove all the entries.

Comment: sorry, i dont get it =(

Comment: @Predict_it You are modifying the collection while iterating over the collection.  This is why you are getting a concurrent modification exception.  Your first loop iterates over all values and the second loop removes all values which match that, so if you didn't get this error, you would remove all elements.

Comment: its still not deleting the same names, only one of them is gone vivaldi = antonio

Comment: @Predict_it I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: this method have to delete all the same names) but its deleting only one of them))

Comment: If you delete all the same names you won't have any left. if you want that just clear the map.

Answer (score 3):

**Here:**

```
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : map.entrySet()){
            String name = pair.getValue();
            removeItemFromMapByValue(map, name); //you are about to delete a map item here!
        }
```

You are modifying the Set that you are **currently** looping through ==> [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: Indeed, and if he really wants to remove items in that loop, he needs to use the Iterator.

Comment: @Aaron unfortunately this method is called in a loop, so it's a bit more complicated ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey, @Predict_it if you like you could use a temporary set `loopSet` and you copy your `map.entrySet` items to it and use if for your loop as alternative _quick & dirty_ fix.

Comment: @Predict_it is the problem still happening?